# C#/XAML App Lifecycle - Jump login page after Terminating app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, lifecycle

In my Windows Store App i've followed the Microsoft guidelines to resume the app after it is terminated(http://goo.gl/oZ7BG).
It all works but after the app is terminated i'd like to jump the login page(that is the first page in the app) and go directly to the Menu page of the app. It's absolutely like the Dropbox app. I know i have to work to the App.xaml.cs and this method:

```
protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        bool appTerminated = false;
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            marketingHP.Common.SuspensionManager.RegisterFrame(rootFrame, "appFrame");

            if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                await marketingHP.Common.SuspensionManager.RestoreAsync();
                appTerminated = true;
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            if (appTerminated)
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage), args.Arguments);
            else if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage), args.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

How can i understand that the app is terminated before?
Note that i've added the bool appTerminated but it works only for suspending...

Answer (score 1):

Read up further on windows 8 app lifecycle here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx

Particularly, notice the section regarding the PreviousExecutionState property and the table included there outlining the different terminated states. It seems like what you would want to do is check the value of PreviousExecutionState, and if that value reflects the condition in which you want to skip the login page (e.g. the user has already logged in), then you should navigate to your homepage, similar to what you've tried to do above.

If you are closing the app manually and windows is not terminating it due to resource constraints, or it was closed unexpectedly, then `appTerminated` won't be set to `true`.

Instead of:

```
if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
```

Include a check to see if the app was terminated by the user:

```
if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated ||
    args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.ClosedByUser)
```

This will catch both when windows terminates the app due to resource constraints and when a user terminates the app manually. Then, on startup from termination, `appTerminated` should be set to true, and the app should navigate directly to `HomePage`.

**edit:**

In answer to your comment, what you could do is inside the App.xaml file, provide logic that changes the arguments passed in the Navigate call. You could do something like this:

```
string navArgs = "FromApp";
if (appTerminated)
{
    navArgs = "FromTerminated";
}
```

Then, just pass this to HomePage when you call Navigate:

```
if (appTerminated)
{
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(HomePage), navArgs);
}
```

Now, in your HomePage code behind file, define the OnNavigatedTo method. This takes a NavigatedEventArgs that you can then cast as some object (in this case as a `String`) and then check to see what was passed:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string navArgs = e.Parameter as String;
    switch (navArgs)
    {
    case "FromApp":
        //Do something here
        break;
    case "FromTerminated":
        //Do something different here
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i will look for sure at this!But how can i recognize in HomePage in LoadState method if i'm coming from LoginPage or from a previous app state?!

Comment: I added onto my original answer, see above :-)